# .NET core NToastNotify nuget package returns a 404 on /_content/NToastNotify/toastr.js?7.0.0.0 but just on PROD

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am using the NToastNotify nuget package (v7.0.0) with `.NET core 3.1`.

```
 services.AddMvc(options =>
 {
     options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
     options.Conventions.Add(new RouteTokenTransformerConvention(
         new SlugifyParameterTransformer()));
  })
  .AddNToastNotifyToastr(new ToastrOptions
  {
      NewestOnTop = true,
      TimeOut = 10000,
      ProgressBar = false,
      PositionClass = ToastPositions.BottomRight
  }, new NToastNotifyOption()
  {
      ScriptSrc = "/js/toastr.min.js",
      StyleHref = "/css/toastr.min.css"
  });
```

I have added the `app.UseNToastNotify();` middleware in the `Configure` method as well as added the `@await Component.InvokeAsync("NToastNotify")` bit in the body tag within the layout page.

Everything works perfectly on development, but on production when it tries to download the `JS` file it return a 404. As you can see I have also tried to override the script source, but still no luck.

The `@await Component.InvokeAsync("NToastNotify")` part will actually render the following

```
<script src=/_content/NToastNotify/toastr.js?7.0.0.0 type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    if (nToastNotify) {
        nToastNotify.init({
            firstLoadEvent: 'DOMContentLoaded',
            messages: [],
            responseHeaderKey: 'X-NToastNotify-Messages',
            requestHeaderKey: 'X-Requested-With',
            libraryDetails:{"varName":"toastr","scriptSrc":"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js","styleHref":"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.css","options":{"positionClass":"toast-bottom-right","timeOut":10000,"newestOnTop":true,"progressBar":false,"type":"success"}},
            disableAjaxToasts:false
        });
    };
</script>
```

I will get the following two errors `GET https://xy.hu/_content/NToastNotify/toastr.js?7.0.0.0 net::ERR_ABORTED 404` and `Uncaught ReferenceError: nToastNotify is not defined`

The whole site runs through Cloudflare. I am not sure if that is the reason why it don~t work on production. By the way this _content folder does not exist on any environment and is download somehow by the nuget package.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, I guess this issue may be related with the Cloudflare hosted folder path. To avoid this issue, I suggest you could try below workaround.

You could add the reference manually in the view, like below:

```
<script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js?7.0.0.0 type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Or directly download the script and add the relative path.